# For loop (element:collection) not making permanent change

Tags: java, for-loop

When going through a collection using a using a for loop using (element:collection) the changes I've made to data only remains the same during the loop.

Here is my code:

```
String[] names = {"bob", "fred", "marcus", "robert", "jack", "steve", "nathan", "tom", "freddy", "sam"};

for(String indexData : names)
{   
    indexData = indexData.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(indexData);
}

System.out.println("this is word 5 in the array: " + names[4]);
```

Output:

```
BOB
FRED
MARCUS
ROBERT
JACK
STEVE
NATHAN
TOM
FREDDY
SAM
this is word 5 in the array: jack
```

My question is using this type of loop how do I make permanent changes?

Comment: you need normal for loop not enhanced loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that with enhanced loop.you need Traditional for loop .`indexData = indexData.toUpperCase();` only change local variable `indexData` .it doesn't affect your array elements .

following `Traditional for loop` will change your array

```
String[] names = {"bob", "fred", "marcus", "robert", "jack", "steve", "nathan", "tom", "freddy", "sam"};


for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++) {   

   names[i]= names[i].toUpperCase();
   System.out.println(indexData);

}

 System.out.println("this is word 5 in the array: " + names[4]);
```

Comment: Ok thanks wasn't sure if it was just temporary or I wasn't doing something right.

Comment: indexData is just a local variable create inside for loop temporary

Comment: @Nathan it doesn't. You're only changing the local variable `indexData` the array itself stays the same.

Comment: no it only  change the termper String indexData after take value from array.for clarify .indexData get assigned value from array then that value get changed .nothing happens to array.

Answer (score 3):

The loop (Element: Collection) is called an enhanced for loop. The ehanced for loop maintains an iterator, and doesn't allow for removal of objects, or use the iterator explicitly.

The way to achieve your desired result is through a standard loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++)
{   
    names[i] = names[i].toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(names[i]);
}
```

Comment: That last `indexData` should be names[i] too though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ListIterator`:

```
String[] names = {"bob", "fred", "marcus", "robert", "jack", "steve", "nathan", "tom", "freddy", "sam"};

ListIterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList(names).listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String name = iterator.next();
    iterator.set(name.toUpperCase());
}
```